# Como puedo guardar los datos que ingreso a un programa en C en un documento .txt o otro

Tags: c

Tengo este código en el que estoy trabajando, es sobre un sistema de agendamiento de citas medicas, lo que quiero es que después de ingresar los datos del paciente (nombre, edad, peso, etc), estos se guarden en un archivo .txt, intente usar

```
FILE *archivo;
 archivo = fopen("citas.txt", "w+");
```

pero no me funciona no entiendo por que, me crea el archivo, me da parte del mensaje, pero no muestra los datos ingresados, por que pasa esto?, Aquí esta el código completo, si lo quieren ver:

https://github.com/mateo16074/agendamiento-de-citas.git

Answer (score 0):

En tu código, la forma en que definiste el modo de escritura `("w+")` en la función mostrarCitas hace que cada vez que se inicializa, sobrescribe el texto existente. Para agregar nuevos textos sin perder los anteriores, debes usar `a` o usa `r+` para leer y escribir

Aquí tienes la función corregida:

```
void mostrarCitas(paciente *pointer) {
  FILE *archivo;
  archivo = fopen("citas.txt", "a"); // Abre el archivo en modo de anexo

  if (archivo == NULL) {
    printf("No se pudo abrir el archivo para escritura.\n");
    return;
  }

  fprintf(archivo, "\n\t ------- Lista de citas de hoy -------\n\n");

  if (pointer == NULL) {
    fprintf(archivo, "\n\n\n ¡No hay citas reservadas para hoy!. Si deseas reservar una cita para hoy, por favor procede.....\n\n\n");
  }

  while (pointer != NULL) {
    fprintf(archivo, "\n\nNúmero de token - %d: ", pointer->numcita);
    fprintf(archivo, "%s (Número de celular: %s)\n", pointer->nombre, pointer->numtel);
    fprintf(archivo, "Edad: %d \n", pointer->edad);
    fprintf(archivo, "Peso: %.2f\n", pointer->peso);
    fprintf(archivo, "Altura: %.2f\n", pointer->altura);
    fprintf(archivo, "Sexo: %s\n", pointer->sexo);
    pointer = pointer->sig;
  }

  fclose(archivo); // Cierra el archivo después de escribir los datos
}
```

Ahora actualiza la lista sin perder la información anterior.

Otra corrección es que el puntero en la función `informacionPaciente` no está reflejando la modificación fuera de la función. Para que se refleje, utiliza un puntero a puntero.

Un puntero a puntero apuntará al puntero original y luego accederá al objeto apuntado por el puntero original y actualizará el puntero original con una nueva dirección. Este cambio se reflejará fuera de la función.